# Graphing logarithmic functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Currently, in my class we just started learning about graphing logarithmic functions and I was absent today so all I have is a worksheet and a blank note sheet that doesn't help with anything really.

I've tried watching videos and they helped me with basic graphing of them, but I get very confused once we get to translating them like f(x) = log(x-1)+2. Also, on most of the problems I've seen there's usually a number between the log and the (x-1), like this log2(x-1)+2 instead of what I put above so I don't know what to do.

So how do I graph the translated log functions, like f(x) = log(x-1)+2, any help?

Comment: Googling around for "function translations" would help you. Works the same with logs as with any other kind of function.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the expression of a function and replace $x$ by $x-1,$
it moves the entire graph of the function $1$ unit to the right.
If you replace $x$ with $x-2,$ it's $2$ units to the right.
For $x+1$ it's one unit to the left. And so forth.

If you take the final output of a function and add $2$, you move the graph $2$ units upward.

These translation ideas are not special to logarithmic functions.
Essentially *any* function you can graph will move like this when
you modify its input or output in these ways.

If you see something like $\log_2,$ the $2$ is the base of the logarithm.
All logarithms have a base; if you are writing $\log$ without an indication
of the base, it means you are assuming the base is the "usual" one,
whatever is "usual" for you.
For most mathematics, the "usual" base is $e$ (that is, we use the natural logarithm).
But in some contexts the "usual" base is $10,$ which I suppose is why $\log_{10}$ has been known as the *common logarithm.*

Answer (score 0):

You can ask [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%20y%3Dlog(x-1)%2B2%20from%201%20to%205) to do the plot for you, getting this
[image]
The $x-1$ just shifts the graph one unit to the right compared to $\log x$.  The $+2$ shifts the graph upward by two units.  When you see $\log_2 x$ that is the base $2$ log instead of base $10$ or $e$

Answer (score 0):

I think some experience is good:

[Desmos.com](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bmiaozuhm8)

Play around with each thing and record how it affects the logarithm.